# Potential leak of an object allocated on line ##and stored into musicPlayController

Tags: ios, memory-leaks

```
- (void)showMusicPlayer
{
[MediaPlayController releaseInstance];
MusicPlayController *musicPlayController = [[MusicPlayController alloc] init];
MusicPlayerViewController *musicPlayerViewController = [musicPlayController createMusicPlayerViewController];

HomeRunManagerAppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[delegate showFullScreenView:musicPlayerViewController];
}
```

Method returns an object-c object with an +1 retain count.

I know I alloc a musicPlayController instance,and it will appear to play the music,but there is just leaking.I am not sure how to solve the warning,(or memory leaking.)
where should I release my object?

I think,

```
MusicPlayController *musicPlayController = [[[MusicPlayController alloc] init] autorelease];
```

is not a useful way.

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to release `musicPlayController`

Either by

```
MusicPlayController *musicPlayController = [[[MusicPlayController alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Or

```
 MusicPlayController *musicPlayController = [[MusicPlayController alloc] init];
MusicPlayerViewController *musicPlayerViewController = [musicPlayController createMusicPlayerViewController];  
[musicPlayController release];
```

Comment: If I release musicPlayController, My Play UI is not able to work well.I don't think it's the right time to release.